# Is there a way to get client host name by cherrypy server

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a cherrypy server on a machine, and i want to get the client identifier from the request. Now i can get the client IP by **cherrypy.request.remote.ip**, but if the client user use a proxy then the IP address will be the proxy address that i don't want, so is there any way for getting the host name of the client machine or some other ways to distiguish the client identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original client IP is usually passed along by proxy with `X-Forwarded-For` header. You can either study the header or use `tools.proxy` setting to automatically rewrite `cherrypy.request.remote.ip`. See `cherrypy.lib.cptools.proxy` for details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a HTTP protocol problem and has nothing to do with python or cherrypy.
HTTP clients don't send their hostname along with requests.

Comment: @diutxx, i got it, then is there some attributes can show the client identifier